# Как добавить кнопки на каждый слайд, если pagination занят под progressbar?

Tags: swiper, navigationcontroller

Всем привет!
Делаю слайдер на swiper.
В слайдере есть прогрессбар и кнопки для каждого слайда. Вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка:

```
<div class="swiper">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        SLIDE 1
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        SLIDE 2
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        SLIDE 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Через элемент .swiper-pagination я вызываю pagination: {type: 'progressbar'}.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить кнопки 01 Заголовок 02 Заголовок 03 Заголовок ?